# How to directly play speech in python without saving to mp3?

Tags: python, gtts

I am trying into convert text to speech in Python using the gTTS module.
Is there a method you can use which does not involve saving the audio to an mp3 file and instead plays the it directly? I have looked online for a while but I still can't find a method which completely avoids saving to files.
Thanks!

Comment: as I remeber this question was few times on Stackoverflow and first you should find them. You can use `io.Bytes` to create file-like object in memory - and this method is used to work with images without saving on disk - but as I rember problem is that modules which can play audio can't work with file-like object but they need filename.

Answer (score 5):

Try using pyttsx3. Usage:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("I will speak this text")
engine.runAndWait()
```

This does not save audio to an mp3 file and works offline.

[Link to source code](https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this function which will give you the option to modify the speed of the spoken text, in the example below, the speed is 178:

```
engine.setProperty("rate", 178)
```